# /bin/sh: @echo: command not found

Tags: linux, bash, makefile, gnu-make

```
run:
    cd ..; \
    @echo $(shell pwd)
```

Throws this:

```
/bin/sh: @echo: command not found
```

The following works, and prints current directory:

```
run:
    @echo $(shell pwd)
```

Do you know why?

Comment: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Echoing

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the error message already suggests:

> `/bin/sh: @echo: command not found`

The actual command that is not found is **`@echo`**, not `echo`. This issue is happening because the shell receives the single line below, since you are escaping the newline character using `\`.

```
cd ..; @echo [output of pwd]
```

You could place the `@` before the `cd` command instead:

```
run:
    @cd ..; \
    echo $(shell pwd)
```

This way, the shell will receive the following line:

```
cd ..; echo [output of pwd]
```

Comment: Thanks: I will accept this as for the "command not found and @. Do you know why it does not print the parent dir - it just prints the current dir.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: @ChrisG. It looks like you're confused which parts are run by `make` and which are passed on to the shell. `$(shell pwd)` is run by `make` before the whole `cd ..; echo /whatever` string is passed to `sh`.

Comment: echo $(shell pwd) just prints the current starting dir, and not "cd .."ing up to the parent.

Comment: See melpomene's comment, try `echo $$(pwd)` instead.

Comment: Ahh ok, hmm.. but it must be possible to move up, right?

Comment: @ChrisG. If you want to print the current directory of the shell, you need something like `cd ..; echo $$PWD` (or `cd ..; pwd`).

Comment: Basically, the execution of `pwd` has to be delayed, so that it is executed by the shell, and not by `make`.